# How to save value( from every single iteration ) of derived type member?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I am not experienced programer in fortran so I need a help about my simple code.
My code is:

```
module derived_type

implicit none

type :: iter_type

  integer :: calc_tmp
  integer :: n_iter

  contains

    procedure :: calc_iter     => calc_iter_process
    procedure :: take_calc_tmp => take_data_calc_tmp
    procedure :: take_n_iter   => take_data_n_iter

end type iter_type

private :: calc_iter_process
private :: take_data_calc_tmp
private :: take_data_n_iter

contains

function calc_iter_process( this, indx_00 ) result( err_tmp )

  class( iter_type )    :: this
  integer, intent( in ) :: indx_00
  logical               :: err_tmp

  err_tmp = .false.

  this%n_iter = 0

  this%calc_tmp = 1

  do while( this%calc_tmp < indx_00 )

    this%n_iter = this%n_iter + 1

    if ( this%n_iter > 50 ) then

      write(*,*) "error - maximal number of iterations !!!"
      err_tmp = .true.
      exit

    end if

    this%calc_tmp = this%calc_tmp + 1

  end do

end function calc_iter_process

function take_data_calc_tmp( this ) result( data_tmp )

  class( iter_type ) :: this
  integer            :: data_tmp

  data_tmp = this%calc_tmp

end function take_data_calc_tmp

function take_data_n_iter( this ) result( data_tmp )

  class( iter_type ) :: this
  integer            :: data_tmp

  data_tmp = this%n_iter

end function take_data_n_iter

end module derived_type

program iteration_values

use, non_intrinsic :: derived_type

implicit none

integer, parameter :: number_00 = 32
logical            :: global_err

type( iter_type ) :: iter_object

global_err = iter_object%calc_iter( number_00 )

if ( global_err ) stop "error - global !!!"

end program iteration_values
```

I need to find way for code modification which can give me a way to keep or save value of 'calc_tmp' in every single iterations.
When I thinking about that I can not imagine how to allocate or deallocate some array which must be dimension same or higher the 'n_iter'.
Is there way for doing that?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark No. I want to know value of  `calc_tmp` in every single iteration( `n_iter = 1 calc_tmp = ? … n_iter = n calc_tmp = ?`) and I want to keep that informations in `iter_object` with methods for taking member values in mentioned iterations?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Okay but I don't now size of that aray because I do not know value of `n_iter`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark This is simple code. I just need a logic of possible solution and afther that I will find a way to implement that logic in my code version which is much more bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of the allocatable attribute and move_alloc.  Here is an example program.  move_alloc is Fortran 2003.  In this example, I'm increasing the size of the array every time its size is exceeded.

```
program temp

implicit none

integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: tempval, calc_tmp_history
integer :: i, j, calc_tmp, totalSize

totalSize = 0
allocate(calc_tmp_history(2))
do i = 1,4
    calc_tmp = 2*i
    if (i > size(calc_tmp_history)) then
        call move_alloc(calc_tmp_history,tempval)
        allocate(calc_tmp_history(2*i))
        do j = 1,i
            calc_tmp_history(j) = tempval(j)
        end do
    end if
    calc_tmp_history(i) = calc_tmp
    totalSize = totalSize + 1
end do

do i = 1,totalSize
    print *, calc_tmp_history(i)
end do
end program
```

Output from this is:

```
2
4
6
8
```